# Cisco PIX 501 Configuration to keep out spammers

Tags: cisco, configuration

I have a Cisco PIX 501 firewall and have been blacklisted because people are able to spam from my email server. How can I configure the firewall so that people cannot use my email server to send spam?

Comment: you sure it's your email server?  More than likely it's a machine on your LAN so in that case, you need to add an acl to permit outbound SMTP to the mail server only (followed by deny all).

Comment: That's not a firewall problem, it's a mail server relay config problem.

Comment: Fix your email server. This problem has nothing to do with your firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Configure it to block all email. If you want to keep using email from inside the PIX, you'll need to fix the problem on the mail server and leave the PIX alone.